# Find the difference of all the values from the first value with Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

This may be very easy question but I am a little bit stuck on that. Is there any easy and fast way to do that?

I will explain with example what I want.

Let us suppose a vector

```
a= [1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80];
```

I want another vector lets say

```
b= [10-1, 20-1, 30-1, 40-1, 50-1, 60-1,70-1,80-1 ];
```

and then divide all the elements of `b` by 15 and save in another vector lets say `c`.

This is just an example in real I have vectors with more than 100 elements so I want to make it automatic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest reading MATLAB's [Basic Matrix Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/basic-matrix-operations.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following. It works:

```
b = a(2:end) - a(1);
c = b/15;
```